# Google In-Page Analytics clickmap errors when using WordPress HTTPS plugin

Tags: ssl, https, google-analytics, wordpress

Having a problem with WordPress HTTPS and Google Analytics' In-Page Analytics. GA's In-Page Analytics essentially provides you with a click heatmap.

Unfortunately, however, I am experiencing problems. GA is alerting me to the following error, and will not display In-Page Analytics data.

## Errors

**Screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luwWj.png

**Captioned**: Error: The website in your settings (redacted) redirects into a different domain (redacted). In-page analytics currently works on only one domain...

## Troubleshooting Steps

- I've ascertained the GA account is set to https:// and not http://.
- I've tried the Chrome extension with similar results. While the In-Page Analytics seems to load, it does not display any data and yields error 20006. Googling yields a variety of different and seemingly irrelevant results.
- I've ascertained this issue also exists in a second site, also using SSL and the WordPress HTTPS plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was nothing wrong on either end. I simply failed to set the Google Analytics property to https:// in both Property settings **and** View settings. Both are necessary to force Google Analytics to use SSL.